# Load and use composer for firebase PHP-JWT

Tags: php, composer-php

My plan ist to enable a JWT SSO login. I read that I need sth like a composer. Read the docu and installed it via puTTy:

```
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer (version 2.2.7) successfully installed to: /var/www/webxxx/html/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
```

Now I have the `composer.phar` in my composer folder. So far so good.

In the docu it now says use this in PHP

`composer require firebase/php-jwt;`

But when I load it in my script, it just says:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'require' (T_REQUIRE) in /var/www/webxxx/html/xxx.net/xxx/xxx.php on line 131`

I have put

`require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

`require("$root/../../html/composer/composer.phar");`

before, but it does not really change sth.

Sorry, I rarely used composer before, but I know there isn't much missing, is there? :<

Answer (score 0):

Composer is just a console tool to manage packages.
Command `composer require firebase/php-jwt` should be executed from console in your project folder. It will install `firebase/php-jwt` into `./vendor` directory. I assume you don't have `composer` installed globally, so instead calling `composer` you can call `php composer.phar`. But in this case you should have `composer.phar`

Comment: Basically `composer` is similar to `npm` for nodejs and `pip` for python